# Fitting Keras L1 models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a simple keras model (normal Lasso linear model) where the inputs are moved to a single 'neuron' `Dense(1, kernel_regularizer=l1(fdr))(input_layer)` but the weights from this model are never set exactly to zero. I find this interesting since scikit-learn's Lasso can set coefficients exactly to zero.

I have used `Adam` and tensorflow's `FtrlOptimizer` for optimisation and they have the same problem.

I've already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146015/is-the-l1-regularization-in-keras-tensorflow-really-l1-regularization) already but this does not explain why sklearn can set values exactly to zero, no to mention how their models converge in ~500ms on my server when the same model in Keras takes 2.4secs with early terminations.

Is this all because of the optimizer being used or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this all because of the optimizer being used or am I missing
>   something?

Indeed. If you look into the actual [function that gets called](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L687) when you fit `Lasso` from scikit-learn (it's called from `ElasticNet` class) you see that it uses different optimization algorithm.

Coordinate Descent in scikit-learn's `ElasticNet` [starts with coefficient vector equal to zero](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L733), and then considers adding nonzero entries one at a time (this is related to stepwise feature selection for linear regression).

Other methods that are used to optimize L1 regularized regression also are work in that way: for example [LARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-angle_regression#Algorithm) (Least-angle regression) can be also used from scikit-learn.

In contrast to that, a [paper on FTRL](https://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dsculley/papers/ad-click-prediction.pdf) algorithm says

> Unfortunately, OGD is not particularly effective at producing
>   sparse models. In fact, simply adding a subgradient
>   of the L1 penalty to the gradient of the loss (Ow`t(w))
>   will essentially never produce coefficients that are exactly
>   zero.

Comment: I know this, this is why in particular I initialize my weights to zero and I used the `FtrlOptimizer` from tensorflow which is a coordinate descent algorithm (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly - this paper is linked in tf documentation on `FtrlOptimizer`...

Comment: You're exactly right, seems like such a dumb question in retrospect. Now I have write a FISTA optimiser or something :( .

Comment: @SARose actually I think it's a very good question - I felt the answer intuitively, but I had to check scikit-learn code to make sure that I was right. Also I wasn't sure what exactly sklearn's LASSO uses internally before.