# L1 regularization doesn't force the weight parameters to become zero

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

My objective is training an autoencoder through SGD. By using tensorflow 1.x, I added L1 regularization for my loss function like this:

```
    ........
    ........

    beta = 10e-3

    n_inputs = X_Train.shape[1]
    n_outputs = n_inputs

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])

    weights1 = tf.get_variable("weights1", shape=[n_inputs, n_hidden], dtype=tf.float32, initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer())  
    weights2 = tf.get_variable("weights2", shape=[n_hidden, n_outputs], dtype=tf.float32, initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer())

    biases1 = tf.get_variable("biases1", shape=[n_hidden], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    biases2 = tf.get_variable("biases2", shape=[n_outputs], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())

    hidden = activation(tf.matmul(X, weights1) + biases1)
    outputs = tf.matmul(hidden, weights2) + biases2 

    reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - X))
    reg_loss = beta * (tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(weights1)) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(weights2))) 

    loss = reconstruction_loss + reg_loss 

    training_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).optimizer.minimize(loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    .......
    .......
```

After training, I counted the number of zero in weights1 matrix. I found that all weights1[i][j] ≠ 0. what's the problem?

Comment: I believe your parameters will oscillate around zero, by adding / substracting the delta = learning rate * regularization constant. If a parameter is positive, and less than delta, it will become negative and again less then delta, and back.

Answer (score 0):

L1 regularization make the network push useless weight toward 0, but it doesn't asssign 0 To them by brute force. They Will near 0 but not at 0.

see: [Is the L1 regularization in Keras/Tensorflow *really* L1-regularization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146015/is-the-l1-regularization-in-keras-tensorflow-really-l1-regularization)

for detailed answers

Comment: Thanks, I know that L2 regularization forces the weight parameters towards zero (but never exactly zero). But L1 regularization forces the weight parameters to become zero

Comment: It's a regularization that modifies the loss (and thus the gradient); it doesn't "force" anything. Have you tried increasing `beta`? This will make the regularization stronger and might lead to the desired results.

Comment: It's complicated but overall the weight are pushed to zero but struggle to reach precisely 0, I edited my answer to add a link to a question with the answers to why is that

Comment: With L1 regularization ( beta = 10e-2 )
w1: [[ 9.1070933e-06 -1.8132891e-05  2.7440405e-05 ...  9.9110139e-06
  -1.9736017e-06 -6.1299079e-06]
 [-3.8850612e-06 -8.6495111e-06  5.6615418e-06 ...  1.3068163e-05
  -1.1937200e-06  1.9667727e-05]
…
Without L1 regularization 
w1: [[ 0.04745267  0.17575645  0.04061595 ...  0.00272357  0.11409388
  -0.26360482]
 [ 0.25440112 -0.40187    -0.22634292 ...  0.16455233  0.0246956
  -0.24465105]
...

How can I encourage sparsity? however, in this case L1 doesn't guarantee it

Comment: How can I use activity regularization with tensorflow 1.x ?